# Oracle ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: oracle

I Can see that this has been asked before but there solution doesnt work. 
'2017-08-31' is throwing an error. What should iot be?

```
 AND TL.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('2017-08-31', 'YYYYMM') || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AND '2017-08-31'
```

Comment: can you share the whole code, from what I can see:

'2017-08-31' doesn't match the format you provided YYYYMM.

maybe you wanted to do:

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('2017-08-31 ' || '01', 'YYYYMMDD'))

Comment: code is over 1200 lines of a procedure! but its originally a CYCLEDATE parameter which im trying to run manually.

Comment: edit - wrong actually

Comment: You are trying to convert to string something that already is a string - to_char('2017-08-31', 'yyyymm'). This makes sense only if '2017-08-31' is actually bind variable of the date type. Is this the case?

Comment: If you are manually changing parameter to a hard-coded string, you will need more conversions: and tl.tl_prcs_date between to_date(to_char(to_date('2017-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyymm') || '01', 'yyyymmdd') and to_date('2017-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Comment: sounds correct. Im trying AND TL.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2017/08/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE ('2017/08/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd').

Comment: Btw. you can just use trunc around date column to get first day of the month: and tl.tl_prcs_date between trunc(to_date('2017-08-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm') and to_date('2017-08-31')

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want

```
AND TL.TL_PRCS_DATE BETWEEN trunc(date '2017-08-31', 'mm') and date  '2017-08-31'
```

The first function call generates the first day of the month for the passed date. Obviously you could pass that as a date literal but no doubt you have your reasons.

Generally it is good practice to specify dates using the ANSI date syntax rather than relying on Oracle to cast a string implicitly.